# Student's t-distribution identity derivation with multiple samples

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let's say I have three samples $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$. Each has its own "true" mean $\mu_i$ and calculated mean $\overline{X}_i$ over $n_i$ measurements ($n = n_1+n_2+n_3$ and $S$, $n-1$ in denominator, standard deviation of all measurements taken together).

I'm interested in deriving identity:

$$\frac{\overline{X}_i - \mu_i}{S} \sqrt{n_i} \sim t(n-4)$$

It's unclear to me how to compute degrees of freedom.
I've tried reformulating the data in number of ways listed in the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_(statistics)) but didn't accomplish anything. I've used $M = \frac{n_1 \overline{X}_1 + n_2 \overline{X}_2 + n_3 \overline{X}_3}{n_1 + n_2 + n_3}$ to express the mean in the calculation of $S$ but didn't find a way to calculate degrees of freedom. DF is necessary to find the right $\chi^2$ and finish the proof.

$$ \frac{\overline{X}_i - \mu_i}{S} \sqrt{n_i} = 
  \frac{\overline{X}_i - \mu_i}{\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n_i}}} \frac{1}{\frac{S}{\sigma}}= Z\,\frac{1}{\frac{S}{\sigma}} = 
\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\frac{\color{red}{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-M)^2}}{(n-1)\,\sigma^2}}} \sim\frac{Z}{\sqrt{\frac{\chi_{n-k}^2}{n-1}}}
\sim t(n-k)$$

As far as I understand the $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ expression should dictate the degrees of freedom. $Z$ is the $Z$-statistic, $x_i$ is a measurement, $M$ is the mean defined above (mean of all data). I'm also not sure if $n-1$ should be in the denominator of $S$ or $n-k$.

Comment: What exactly did the question do to deserve a downvote? I'd gladly improve it.

Comment: Not my down-vote (not yet, anyhow), but here are possibilities: (1) You must mean $S,$ somehow computable from data, not $\sigma$ for the SD. (2) The terminology 'Bessel corrected' is not widely used, more transparent to give formula. (3) 'Union' of RV's is unclear (to me, anyhow). (4) Expr pretty clearly not t distributed as it stands. (5) No clue as to what you may have tried or where this came from So no clue as to the level of your course or background. So no clue how to be helpful.

Comment: @BruceET The task of proving the identity was given to me at the course I'm taking. I do not know if the identity is correct.

Comment: The expression in red print in your most recent edit, is _not_ used in finding the $S_p^2$ of my Answer. I'm not saying it is wrong. I believe $\sum_j(\bar X_j - M))^2$ is used in computing MS(Factor); if so, it does not seem relevant to a t statistic used to find individual  CIs for $\mu_j$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question is still not clear after edit. I'm guessing you want to get a CI for one of the $\mu_i,$ based on the square root of the pooled variance often denoted as $$S_p^2 = \frac{\sum_j (n_j -1)S_j^2}{n_1 + n_2 + n_3 - 3},$$
which is also the MS(Error) of a one-factor ANOVA.

Taking data $X_{ji},$ for $i = 1,\dots,n_j$ from just one of the groups,
you would have $\frac {\mu_j - \bar X_{j.}}{S_j/\sqrt{n_j}} \sim T(n_j - 1).$
In the absence of observations from other treatment groups, this would be
used to find a CI for $\mu_j.$

However, if you have made the assumption that the group $\sigma_j$ are 
all equal to a common $\sigma,$ then there is additional information
for estimating $\sigma$ in the data for the other treatment groups. 
Accordingly, $\frac{(n - 3)S_p^2}{\sigma^2} \sim Chisq(n - 3),$ where
$n = n_1 + n_2 + n_3.$ Then 
$$\frac {\mu_j - \bar X_{j.}}{S_p/\sqrt{n_j}} 
= \frac {\sqrt{n_j}(\mu_j - \bar X_{j.})}{S_p} \sim T(n - 3).$$

Only $\bar X_{j.}$ has information about $\mu_j.$ Consequently, the numerator
of this t statistic is based on $\frac{\bar X_{j.} = \mu_j}{\sigma/\sqrt{n_j}} \sim Norm(0,1).$ Also, its denominator is based on the square root of
 $\frac{(n - 3)S_p^2}{\sigma^2} \sim Chisq(n - 3),$ as above. Because
there is more information about $\sigma^2$ in $S_p^2$ than in  $S_j^2,$ and larger
degrees of for the t distribution, this second t statistic tends to
give narrower CIs for individual $\mu_j.$

*Note.* If you are familiar with the one-factor (one-way) ANOVA procedure in Minitab, you may recognize this as the method used to give separate 95% CIS
for group means that Minitab prints beneath its one-factor ANOVA tables.

Comment: Without assuming that $\sigma = \sigma_j$ , the expression, even with $t(n-3)$, couldn't be correct?

Comment: Without that assumption, I don't even see a justification for computing $S_p^2.$ Also, $M$ is difficult to interpret without assuming all $\mu_j$'s are equal. What we're entirely missing here is the _context_ of the relationship you're examining, and the reason for wanting to know it's dist'n.

Comment: True, I did forget to mention that I wanted to calculate CI for each $\mu_j$. For some reason the task wants me to use $S_p$, there's no mention of having the assumption that $\sigma = \sigma_j$.

Comment: Implicitly, saying to "use $S_p$" _is_ saying to assume variances equal. I guess I'm done here. If you have what you need, please click the check mark to remove this from our list of questions that still need answers. If not, please leave an explicit Comment, and maybe someone else will provide the answer you're looking for.

Comment: Okay, let's say it is implicit. Is there some formal way of showing that the degrees of freedom is $n-3$? It's obvious that CI are better with higher degree of freedom (higher than $n_i - 1$).

Comment: $S_p^2$ has sum of DFs of $S_1^2,\, S_2^2.\, S_3^2.$ That's $(n_1-1)+(n_2 - 1) + (n_3 - 1) = n - 3.$ Essentially, sum of three chi-squared RVs.